# Deploy the angular site and graphql api in azure

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure-web-app-service

I have created an angular site that uses API written in node js and graph al using mysql data base. I want to deploy it in azure. I am new to azure deployment can any one give me suggestion on how to deploy the website and API in azure using FTP.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this manual, assuming you only want to deploy/ attach your back-end to the azure cloud

http://kabaehr.de/blog/deploying-a-node.js-graphql-api-to-azure/

Comment: Thanks for your replay I have followed the link provided above but I am getting error as below attached screenshot

Comment: Added image in the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `process.env.PORT` for handling the named-pipe port in Azure, see listen additional port `Microsoft Azure Nodejs`.
solution 2, you'll need to enable logging of stdout and stderr for further troubleshooting. See How to enable BLOB-logging for a Node.js Api App on Azure?

or refer to this issue of GitHub
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/417#issuecomment-244471687

Comment: I have tried that then also the same error is there.
I hve enabled the log it coming like 
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: make sure where you are using (let, const, function, class)  `"use strict";` is written on top of the file or the function

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now its deployed I have added use strict in the iisnode.yml.